# React : async setState updates to late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, frontend

I'm learning React.js, and trying to develop a simple fight game.

I try to update state (code below) to define whose turn it is to hit:

```
this.setState({ whoseRound: rand }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.whoseRound)
})
```

Then, I start a while loop. Inside my loop, I want to know whose round it is to attack, using my state `whoseRound` initiated before.

**My probleme is :** As the function `setState` is asynchronous, when I start my loop, the value of my state is still at "0". And obviously, I have the same problem for the end of my `runRound()` method.

How can I do to properly resolve that problem ?

thanks to everyone.

```js
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      characters: [], //contains Array of characters objects
      readyToFight: false, // character selected or not
      firstPlayerCharacter: null, //contains key of character on select
      secndPlayerCharacter: null, //contains key of character on select
      whoseRound: 0 // defines whose character attacks
    }
  }

  //Run the fight
  setFight = () => {
    let firstFighter = this.state.characters[this.state.firstPlayerCharacter]
    let secndFighter = this.state.characters[this.state.secndPlayerCharacter]

    this.initiateFight(firstFighter, secndFighter);
  }

  //initiate fight rounds
  initiateFight = (firstFighter, secndFighter) => {

    // set who attacks first randomly => returns 1 or 2
    var rand = randomDice(1, 2)
    this.setState({whoseRound: rand}, () => {console.log('test:' + this.state.whoseRound)})

    while(firstFighter.stats.health > 0 || secndFighter.stats.healthh > 0){
      /* !!! depending on whoseRound is, we set an attacker 
    and a defenser !!! My probleme is that 
    this.state.whoseRound's value is 0 
    at this moment, as the sateState 
    method is async. */
      1 === this.state.whoseRound ? this.runRound(firstFighter, secndFighter) : this.runRound(secndFighter, firstFighter)
    }
  }

  // Lance les actions définies pour un round
  runRound = (attacker, defender) => {
    let hit = false
    let cc = false
    let damages

    hit = randomDice(0, 100) <= this.getHitChances(attacker, defender)
    cc = randomDice(0, 100) <= this.getCriticalChances(attacker, defender)
    damages = this.getDamages(attacker, defender, cc)

    if(hit)
    {
      //console.log(attacker.name + ' attaque ' + defender.name + ' et lui occtroie ' + damages + ' points de dégats')
      //console.log('les points de vie de ' + defender.name + ' passent de ' + defender.stats.health + ' à ' + (defender.stats.health - damages))
      defender.stats.health -= damages
    }

    //Now, it's the other character's turn
    1 === this.state.whoseRound ? this.setState({whoseRound: 2}) : this.setState({whoseRound: 1})

  }
  
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you could use event emitters, or if using flux, dispatcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two simple things that you could do,

**First:** Execute whatever you want to in the `setState callback`

```
this.setState({whoseRound: rand}, () => {
     console.log('test:' + this.state.whoseRound)
     while(firstFighter.stats.health > 0 || secndFighter.stats.healthh > 0){
      /* !!! depending on whoseRound is, we set an attacker 
    and a defenser !!! My probleme is that 
    this.state.whoseRound's value is 0 
    at this moment, as the sateState 
    method is async. */
      1 === this.state.whoseRound ? this.runRound(firstFighter, secndFighter) : this.runRound(secndFighter, firstFighter)
    }
})
```

**Second:** Instead of using `state` use `rand`, since that is what you are updating state with

```
while(firstFighter.stats.health > 0 || secndFighter.stats.healthh > 0){
      /* !!! depending on whoseRound is, we set an attacker 
    and a defenser !!! My probleme is that 
    this.state.whoseRound's value is 0 
    at this moment, as the sateState 
    method is async. */
      1 === rand ? this.runRound(firstFighter, secndFighter) : this.runRound(secndFighter, firstFighter)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was blocked on a solution that involve trying to change my setState to synchrone. It helped a lot ;)